# How to get the exact position of the array of a datatable?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datatables

I'm doing crud (CREATE, READ, UPDATE, DELETE) table in PHP + JS + SQL and I want to do the next:

I have a table with users (I take this data from my DB):

[image]

When I click on the "Edit" icon (green edit icon), I can type on the values of my table.

[image]

I don't know how to get the exact position of the array (to show all of those users, I'm using an array, ofc) to save it in a variable for later do a query to update the information.

Do you know what I'm trying to say, guys?

Here is my code:

```
<table class='table table-bordered table-hover' class='display' style='width:100%; text-align: center;' id='tableTest'>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Editar</th>
                <th>Nombre</th>
                <th>Apellido 1</th>
                <th>Apellido 2</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Eliminar</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php foreach ($res_table as $r){ ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><span class="fas fa-edit editar grow" onclick="updateData(this)"></span></td>
                    <td><?php echo $r->usuario?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $r->apellido1?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $r->apellido2?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $r->email?></td>
                    <td><span class="fas fa-trash-alt grow" onclick="updateData(this)"></span></td>
                </tr>
            <?php } ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>

<div id="contenedorForm">

</div>
```

And here is my JS.

```
    // Función para actualizar los datos de la tabla.
    function updateData(nodo){          
        var nodoTd = nodo.parentNode; //Nodo TD
        var nodoTr = nodoTd.parentNode; //Nodo TR
        var nodoContenedorForm = document.getElementById('contenedorForm'); //Nodo DIV
        var nodosEnTr = nodoTr.getElementsByTagName('td');
        var editData = nodosEnTr[0].textContent;
        var usuario = nodosEnTr[1].textContent;
        var apellido1 = nodosEnTr[2].textContent;
        var apellido2 = nodosEnTr[3].textContent;
        var email = nodosEnTr[4].textContent;
        var opciones = nodosEnTr[5].textContent;
        
        var nuevoCodigoHtml =
            '<td><span class="fas fa-edit editar grow" onclick="updateData(this)"></span></td>'+
            '<td><input onblur="getIdInputFromDatabase()" type="text" name="usuario" id="usuario" value="' + usuario + '" size="20"></td>'+
            '<td><input onblur="getIdInputFromDatabase()" type="text" name="apellido1" id="apellido1" value="' + apellido1 + '" size="20"></td>'+
            '<td><input onblur="getIdInputFromDatabase()" type="text" name="apellido2" id="apellido2" value="' + apellido2 + '" size="20"></td>'+
            '<td><input onblur="getIdInputFromDatabase()" type="text" name="email" id="email" value="' + email + '" size="20"></td>' + 
            '<td><span class="fas fa-trash-alt editar grow" onclick="updateData(this)"></span></td>';
        
        nodoTr.innerHTML = nuevoCodigoHtml;

        nodoContenedorForm.innerHTML =
            'Pulse Aceptar para guardar los cambios o cancelar para cancelActionlos' +
            '<form name = "formulario" action="general" method="get" onsubmit="capturarEnvio()" onreset="cancelAction()">' +
            '<input class="boton" type = "submit" value="Aceptar">' +
            '<input class="boton" type="reset" value="Cancelar">';
    }

    function getIdInputFromDatabase(){
        alert("I NEED TO KNOW THE POSITION OF THE ARRAY WHERE I DID ON BLUR");
    }

// Data tables.
        $(function () {
            $('#tableTest').DataTable({
                "language": {"url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.20/i18n/Spanish.json"},  
                "paging": true,
                "lengthChange": false,
                "searching": true,
                "ordering": true,
                "info": false,
                "autoWidth": false,
                "scrollX": false
            });
        });
</script>
```

How Can I do this, guys? Can you help me? I searched on the DataTables API but Im lost.
Thank you in advance!

Have a good day!

Comment: I'll take a guess that your data in your DB has a primary key, possibly called `id`.  So you add the id somewhere to the row, either as an attribute to the `tr` `<tr data-id='<?php echo $r->id?>'>` or in a hidden `td` `<td style='display:none;'><?php echo $r->id?></td>` (don't use style='display:none' use a css to hide it).  Then your edit knows which row is being edited by its ID (rather than row index, which may not match)

Comment: Oh yes ... I have that field called ID! Nice idea! What if I wanted to access that ID to store it in a variable and do a query later? For example, from that id, run an SQL update statement. How can I do that? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Same as you already do, if a column then `nodoTr[0].textContent` (and adjust your other column indices).  If a data-attr then `$(nodoTr).data("id")` (or vanilla js equivalent).

Comment: Thanks a lot, man!!!!!! I can't vote you because Im new in StackOverflow, but really thanks!

Comment: For the record, this "update by offset" method has been the source of troubles in a number of applications. The trouble comes when two or more people are working on the data and one deletes a record, causing the other's changes to be applied to the incorrect record because the relative offset has changed. Using the record's unique ID as mentioned by freedomn-m is the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have a field called `ID` you can store that in the HTML when you first build your table (in the `<?php foreach ($res_table as $r){ ?>` loop), this can be either as an attribute to the `tr`, eg

```
<tr data-id='<?php echo $r->id?>'>
```

or in a hidden td, eg

```
<td style='display:none;'><?php echo $r->id?></td>
```

(don't use style='display:none' use a css to hide it, just an example here to show it's hidden).

Then your edit can know which row is being edited by its ID (rather than row index, which may not match the DB `ID`)

```
var id = $(nodoTr).data("id")
```

or

```
var id = nodoTr[0].textContent;
```

You then need to pass that `id` to your inline edit, in some way, this could be by adding as a parameter to the onsubmit, eg:

```
'... onsubmit="capturarEnvio(' + id + ')" ...'
```

Comment: Thanks. You are the boss!